# "Could not find a declaration file" for react-scripts-ts app on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, typescript, heroku

I have a React with Typescript frontend for a Heroku app, with the client stored under `client/`, and in my top-level package.json I have the following:

```
...
"heroku-prebuild": "cd client && yarn && yarn run build",
...
```

In the client folder, I have the Typescript and related dependencies under `devDependencies`, and the client builds (`react-scripts-ts build`) fine locally. However on Heroku, I get the following error in the build output:

```
/tmp/build_c4236577d559126ce645e4d8e04323f1/client/src/App.tsx
(3,37): Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router-dom'. '/tmp/build_c4236577d559126ce645e4d8e04323f1/client/node_modules/react-router-dom/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/react-router-dom` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-router-dom';`
```

However I clearly have `@types/react-router-dom` in my client's package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/jest": "^23.3.10",
  "@types/node": "^10.12.12",
  "@types/react": "^16.7.13",
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
  "typescript": "^3.2.2",
  "tslint": "^5.11.0"
}
```

The problem is only showing up on Heroku. How can I fix this?